# iPhone How to have mapview load showing the whole of the UK zoom level?

Tags: iphone, annotations, nsarray, android-mapview

I want the map to load showing the entire UK when it initialises.

I have about 20 annotations throughout the UK so want it to display them all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set a coordinate around center of UK and adjust zoom level.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
MKMapRect flyTo = MKMapRectNull;
NSArray *array = mapView.annotations;
for(MyAnnotation *an in array)
{
    MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(an.coordinate);
    MKMapRect rect = MKMapRectMake(0, 0, point.x, point.y);
    if(MKMapRectIsNull(flyTo))
        flyTo = rect;
    else
        flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, rect);
}

mapView.visibleMapRect = flyTo;
```